# Coalesce fields in a .net MVC 4 model without getting "Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported" from LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

The answer to this question gave rise to this other question: [How to use LINQ expressions as static members of classes in queries when the class is related multiple times to a second class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649655)

I have an existing ASP.net MVC 4 site which I need to modify.

The core entity within this site are Items that are for sale, which are created by several different companies and divided into several categories. My task is to allow each company its own optional alias for the global categories. Getting the two categories set up in the database and model was no problem, making the application use the new optional alias when it exists and default to the global otherwise is where I'm struggling to find the optimal approach.

Adding a coalesce statement to every LINQ query will clearly work, but there are several dozen locations where this logic would need to exist and it would be preferable to keep this logic in one place for when the inevitable changes come.

The following code is my attempt to store the coalesce in the model, but this causes the "**Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.**" error to be thrown when the LINQ query is executed. I'm unsure how I could achieve something similar with a different method that is more LINQ friendly.

Model:

```
public class Item
{
    [StringLength(10)]
    [Key]
    public String ItemId { get; set; }

    public String CompanyId { get; set; }

    public Int32 CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual GlobalCategory GlobalCategory { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId, CategoryId")]
    public virtual CompanyCategory CompanyCategory { get; set; }

    public String PreferredCategoryName
    { 
        get{
            return (CompanyCategory.CategoryAlias == null || CompanyCategory.CategoryAlias == "") ? GlobalCategory.CategoryName : CompanyCategory.CategoryAlias;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller LINQ examples:

```
       var categories = (from i in db.Items
                          where i.CompanyId == siteCompanyId
                          orderby i.PreferredCategoryName
                          select i.PreferredCategoryName).Distinct();

        var itemsInCategory = (from i in db.Items
                          where i.CompanyId == siteCompanyId
                          && i.PreferredCategoryName == categoryName
                          select i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one you are using a compiled function (`getPreferredCategoryName`) in the query, unless EF knows how to translate that you are in trouble.

Try the following in item definition:

```
public static Expression<Func<Item,String>> PreferredCategoryName
{
    get
    {
        return i => (i.CompanyCategory.CategoryAlias == null || i.CompanyCategory.CategoryAlias == "") ? 
                     i.GlobalCategory.CategoryName : 
                     i.CompanyCategory.CategoryAlias;
    }
}
```

Which is used as follows:

```
var categories = db.Items.Where(i => i.CompanyID == siteCompanyId)
                         .OrderBy(Item.PreferredCategoryName)
                         .Select(Item.PreferredCategoryName)
                         .Distinct();
```

This should work as you have a generically available uncompiled expression tree that EF can then parse.

Comment: I had messed around with that approach but couldn't figure out how to make it work with the query style LINQ statement, using the object style LINQ statement as in your example was the missing piece. Thanks.